# (edited)$\mathrm{Dom}(R_1 \cup R_2) \subseteq \mathrm{Dom}(R_1) \cup \mathrm{Dom}(R_2)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

For sets $A,B,C,D$, let $R_1, R_2$ be relations such as $R_1 : A \rightarrow B, R_2 : C\rightarrow D$. Then is the following sentence true?
$$\mathrm{Dom}(R_1 \cup R_2) \subseteq \mathrm{Dom}(R_1) \cup \mathrm{Dom}(R_2)$$

I guess that it is true, but I don't know how to prove it by predicate logic. I can prove that $R_1 \cup R_2$ is also relation that $R_1 \cup R_2 : A\cup C \rightarrow B\cup D$. If the above statement is false, what condition is needed for the statement being true?

*edit

I read drhab's answer. I think there is a problem in setting domains. Remark that $R_1 : A \rightarrow B$ then
$$x \in \mathrm{Dom}(R_1) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \in B : (x,y) \in R_1$$
In addition the existential quantifier holds distributive law with $\vee$ which means "or", and the following property.
$$\exists x, p(x) \vee q(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x, p(x) \vee \exists x, q(x)$$
$$\exists p(x), q(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x,p(x)\wedge q(x)$$
Using the above definition and properties there is a problem.
\begin{align}
&a \in \mathrm{Dom}(R_1 \cup R_2 )\\
\Leftrightarrow& \exists b \in B\cup D : (a,b)\in R_1 \cup R_2\\
\Leftrightarrow& \exists b \in B\cup D : (a,b) \in R_1 \vee (a,b)\in R_2 \\
\Leftrightarrow& \exists b_1 \in B\cup D : [(a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists  b_2 \in B\cup D: [(a,b_2) \in R_2] \\
\Leftrightarrow& \exists b_1: [ b_1 \in B\cup D \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_2 : [b_2 \in B\cup D \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2 ]\\
\Leftrightarrow& \exists b_1 : [(b_1 \in B \vee b_1\in D) \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1 ] \vee \exists b_2 : [(b_2 \in B \vee b_2\in D) \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2 ]\\ 
\Leftrightarrow& \exists b_1 : [b_1 \in B \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_1:[b_1 \in D \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_2 : [b_2 \in B \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2] \vee \exists b_2:[b_2 \in D \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2]
\end{align}
In the last statement, $\exists b_1 : [b_1 \in B \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_2:[b_2 \in D \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2]$ means $a\in \mathrm{Dom}(R_1) \cup \mathrm{Dom}(R_2)$. So, $\mathrm{Dom}(R_1) \cup \mathrm{Dom}(R_2) \subseteq \mathrm{Dom}(R_1 \cup R_2)$ is proved, because 
\begin{align}
&\exists b_1 : [b_1 \in B \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_2:[b_2 \in D \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2]\\
\Rightarrow& \exists b_1 : [b_1 \in B \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_1:[b_1 \in D \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_2 : [b_2 \in B \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2] \vee \exists b_2:[b_2 \in D \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2]
\end{align}

I think the "$\Rightarrow$" can be changed into "$\Leftrightarrow$". To do this, $\exists b_1:[b_1 \in D \wedge (a,b_1) \in R_1] \vee \exists b_2 : [b_2 \in B \wedge (a,b_2) \in R_2]$ should be false, but I think if we choose a suitable relation such that $b_1, b_2$ which are in $B\cap D$, then this statement can be also true, contrary to my purpose.

How did you prove these things?

Comment: You are making things needlessly complicated. The equivalences that you practicize are only true under extra conditions. E.g. a statement like $x\in\mathsf{Dom}(R_1)\iff\exists y\in B[\langle x,y\rangle\in R_1]$ is true under the condition that $R_1\subseteq A\times B$. This in contrast with the statement $x\in\mathsf{Dom}(R_1)\iff\exists y[\langle x,y\rangle\in R_1]$ (used in my answer) which is simply true and does not rest on any condition.

Comment: "..So $\mathsf{Dom}(R_1)\cup\mathsf{Dom}(R_2)\subseteq\mathsf{Dom}(R_1\cup R_2)$ is proved..." Don't you mean the other side? $\mathsf{Dom}(R_1)\cup\mathsf{Dom}(R_2)\subseteq\mathsf{Dom}(R_1\cup R_2)$ is a direct consequence of $R_i\subseteq R_1\cup R_2\implies\mathsf{Dom}(R_i)\subseteq\mathsf{Dom}(R_1\cup R_2)$ for $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **any** set $U$ you can define: $$\mathsf{Dom}(U):=\{x\mid\exists y[\langle x,y\rangle\in U\}$$

Then evidently the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in\mathsf{Dom}(U\cup V)$
- $\exists y\langle x,y\rangle\in U\cup V$
- $\exists y[\langle x,y\rangle\in U\vee\langle x,y\rangle\in V]$
- $[\exists y\langle x,y\rangle\in U]\vee[\exists y\langle x,y\rangle\in V]$
- $x\in\mathsf{Dom}(U)\vee x\in\mathsf{Dom}(V)$
- $x\in\mathsf{Dom}(U)\cup\mathsf{Dom}(V)$

So we have:$$\mathsf{Dom}(U\cup V)=\mathsf{Dom}(U)\cup\mathsf{Dom}(V)$$

---

$R_1$ is a relation $A\to B$ iff $R_1\subseteq A\times B$ and $R_2$ is a relation $C\to D$ iff $R_2\subseteq C\times D$.

Then evidently $R_1\cup R_2\subseteq (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$ so is a relation $A\cup C\to B\cup D$, as you suspected.

Comment: I think there is a problem in your statements. I edited the question.

Comment: If the mentioned statements are numbered: $1,2,3,4,5,6$, then can you find any $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that statement $i$ and statement $i+1$ are **not** equivalent? And are the statements $x\in\mathsf{Dom}(R_1)$ and $\exists y[\langle x,y\rangle\in R_1]$ indeed equivalent? If so, and you cannot find such $i$, then what is wrong in my answer??

Comment: i got it. thank you for your answer

Comment: You are welcome.